Assembler vs Compiler in AsmJit
In AsmJit, what is the difference between the asmjit::Assembler, and asmjit::Compiler?
They are both used to generate code. When should one be preferred over the other?

assembler lets you generate any arbitrary code, compiler is focused on function generation, so it automatically handles stack/allocation/etc for you
